# Reaching Connect API's hourly request limit for this user and application?

Tags: governorlimits, customer-community, lightning-community, limits, connect-api

I`ve got this type of error during the work in Lightning Community:

> You have reached the Connect API's hourly request limit for this user
>   and application. Please try again later.

My API Requests for last 24 hours are far away from the limits.
I also found this statement:

> Salesforce has a limit of 1000 (up to 3000) API call limit per user per hour

But, this cannot be happening.

Are there any ways I can find what triggered that limits?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @ChiragMehta, I created SFDC support case and they solved that.

Comment: thanks @m_konyk!

Answer (score 1):

Log a case with support. They have tools to troubleshoot. Alternatively, if you own the Event Monitoring product, you can do the analysis yourself, looking at the oDataCallout event type. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_externalodatacallout.htm